# Remove remainders from bitmap after background removal

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, bitmap

I have this image and I want to remove the background to isolate the green picture. The background is not completely black but it contains some pixels having the same color of other pixels inside the green picture. [image]
I have used this

```
    private void ButtonFilterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PixelFormat pxf = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
  Bitmap bitmap = ((Bitmap)(_smartLabForm.pictureBox1.Image));
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
  BitmapData bmpData =
  bitmap.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
  IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
  int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * bitmap.Height;
  byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];
  Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);
  for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
  {
    if (rgbValues[counter] < 15 &&
        rgbValues[counter + 1] < 15 &&
        rgbValues[counter + 2] < 15)
    {
      rgbValues[counter] = 255;
      rgbValues[counter + 1] = 255;
      rgbValues[counter + 2] = 255;
    }
  }
  Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes);
  bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
  _smartLabForm.Refresh();
}
```

and what I obtain is this:
[image]

How can I remove the "noise" remaining without damage the green picture and without affecting the performance?
Thank you?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a quite complex topic in computer vision ([image segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation)). Covering the advanced techniques would be way too broad. But here is quick and simple idea that may get the job done:

Increase the threshold enough that all background pixels fall below it. When checking if a pixel should be removed, also compare all pixels in a certain neighborhood (e.g. circular radius) with the threshold. Only remove it if they are **all** below the threshold.

That way you remove pixels less agressively when you are near the feature region.

Comment: _When checking if a pixel should be removed, also compare all pixels in a certain neighborhood (e.g. circular radius) with the threshold._ This is the key. Also repeating the process until it looks good. His current threshold seems to be ok, but actually  __summing up__ the values of all neighbours will help.

Comment: I've used this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/336915/Connected-Component-Labeling-Algorithm and it seems to work QUITE well, but unfortunately some pixels survives around the image. Thank you